# Vacuum bubble with the $Z$-boson

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, regularization

I'm interested in computing the vacuum bubble diagram of a single $Z$-boson. The propagator for a massive vector is
$$
D_{\mu\nu}(k_\mu) = \frac{i}{k^2 - m_Z^2}\left(g_{\mu\nu} - \frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{m_Z^2}\right),
$$
or so I believe. The vacuum bubble diagram (with one mass insertion, which I believe should just be $g^{\mu\nu} m_{Z}^2$) is then
$$
\int^{\Lambda} \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}D_\mu^\mu m_Z^2\sim \Lambda^4.
$$
This is, however, not what I would expect. The divergent part of $\left(g_{\mu\nu} - \frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{m_Z^2}\right)$ typically cancels when contracted with a vertex, so I expect the vacuum bubble diagram to be
$$
\int^\Lambda \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{m_Z^2}{k^2 - m_{Z}^2}\sim \Lambda^2 m_Z^2.
$$
This leads me to believe that the vertex I inserted is incorrect, but I don't see where I've made my mistake.

I'm certainly forgetting something simple, so any help identifying my error would be appreciated!

EDIT: After doing some more reading, it seems that the typical argument that the $k_\mu k_\nu$ part of $D_{\mu\nu}$ must vanish in the path integral in the unitary gauge (which is the gauge I'm working in), and therefore the action is that of three independent massive scalars.

This is sensible to me, however I am not sure how one would arrive at this directly from a Lagrangian of the form
$$
L = -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + \frac12 m_Z^2 Z_\mu Z^\mu,
$$
where $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu Z_\nu - \partial_\nu Z_\mu$.

Comment: With this lagrangian you can't have a $Z$ vacuum bubble since it lacks interactions. That's a free massive vector field lagrangian which do not contain self interactions

Comment: You can find here [https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.6213](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.6213) eq. (53), the propagator for the $Z$ boson. Note that it differs from the Proca propagator you wrote.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Thanks for the reference - the difference in propagator comes down to a choice of gauge. In particular, taking $\xi\to\infty$ yields the unitary gauge that I'm working in. Part of the reason for working in the unitary gauge is that only the physical degrees of freedom propagate (i.e. the two transverse and one longitudinal modes of the Z).

Comment: @LolloBoldo Could you explain further? My understanding is that even a free massive theory will contribute to the vacuum energy.

Comment: @Guy what LolloBoldo is referring to here is that your Lagrangian does not contain any interactions now by definition a vacuum bubble is a diagram in the perturbative expansion of the partition function with no external legs. However we also know that the vertices in such Diagramms are generated by interactions i.e. terms with more than two fields as we define the propagator to be the "interaction" only containing 2 field instances (of the same field assuming no higher order derviatives) .  As your Lagrangian does not contain any such terms there is nothing to close your propagator together

Comment: @ThomasTappeiner how do I reconcile this with the general 1 loop effective potential, which only depends on the masses of fields? (See e.g. the discussion around eq 10 in http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/230A/HW5sol.pdf)

Comment: @Guy as stated by Thomas, to create a bubble in perturbation theory you need a vertex with a minimun of 3 fields. In your lagrangian you have no vertex of such type so you can't form a diagram containing closed bubbles since vertices to close such a bubble are lacking.

Comment: The work you posted is a simple model of the Higgs mechanism and it has nothing to do with vacuum bubbles, that's the mechanism of spontaneous symmetry breaking of a gauge symmetry

Comment: The effective potential for the Higgs is generated at one loop as a sum of vacuum bubbles, or so I thought?